# javascript conditional returning unexpected result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, conditional-statements

I'm doing a simple number comparison on the keyUp event of an input field.  For some reason, I'm not getting the expected result, and I can't figure out why.  What *should* happen is that if the user-entered number is larger than that stored in the html attribute, the background should turn red, otherwise it stays white.  Simply entering '9' will turn the background red. ??

```
var admin = $('input[name="diskStorage"]').attr('data-adminstorage'); // 2097152000

$('#new-user input[name="diskStorage"]').keyup(function(){

    if(admin < $(this).val())
        $(this).css('background','red');
    else
        $(this).css('background','white');
});
```

When I debug these values, `if(2097152000 < 549)` is returning true. Here's the html, in case that makes any difference:

```
<form action="administrate.php" method="post" id="new-user">
<table><tbody><tr>
...
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Disk Storage Limit:</td>
    <td>
   <input type="text" data-adminStorage="2097152000" name="diskStorage" value="" /> megaBytes<br />
    <span id="info"></span></td>
...
  </tr></tbody></table>
```

Here it is live: http://jsfiddle.net/JMC_Creative/dqAJj/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.attr` and `.val()` return `String` objects - use the unary `+` operator to convert it to a numeric value.

```
var admin = $('input[name="diskStorage"]').attr('data-adminstorage');
admin = +admin;

if(admin < +$(this).val()) {
   //...
}
```

Comment: Unary `+` is a better way than `parseInt(str, 10)` in my opinion. Example: `+str` instead of `parseInt(str, 10)`.

Comment: @Reid In what way is it "better"?

Comment: That isn't true. `'2097152000' < '549'` is perfectly valid and results in `true`.

Comment: @Jacob: Shorter amount of characters and much more efficient.

Comment: @Reid: I support you, this is probably the best way, imo. Altho my answer takes even less characters lol.

Comment: @Jacob Is there a reason I couldn't do: `var admin = +$('input[name="diskStorage"]').attr('data-adminstorage');` ?

Comment: @JMCCreative Of course not, that will work just fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `/1` after retrieving the admin value, to make it a number not a string.

```
var admin = $('input[name="diskStorage"]').attr('data-adminstorage')/1;
```

Edit: also on the this.val:

```
$(this).val()/1;
```

Comment: There's `parseInt(str, 10)` for that.. no need to use hacks like that (they are very likely to cause bad things in JavaScript)

Comment: yes I know, but I don't see how this could cause a bad thing, in a error scenario, both will return `NaN`

Comment: Usually, I go with the option that takes less amount of code, if it is basically the same. Your users have to wait more to download your cleanness lol

Answer (score 0):

They are probably both strings. You should convert them to numbers first:

```
var admin = Number($('input[name="diskStorage"]').attr('data-adminstorage')); // 2097152000

$('#new-user input[name="diskStorage"]').keyup(function(){

    if(admin < Number($(this).val()))
        $(this).css('background','red');
    else
        $(this).css('background','white');
});
```